# Supremum of family of functions in $L^1(\mu)$ is in $L^1(\mu)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $S$ be a family of functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that are uniformly bounded. Assume that the functions of $S$ are in $L^1(\mu)$, where $\mu = e^{-2|x|}L$, where $L$ is the Lebesgue measure. How can I prove that $u:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$u(x) = \limsup_{y \to x} \sup\{v(y): v \in S\}$$ is also in $L^1(\mu)$ if we assume that $\sup\{v(y): v \in S\} < \infty$ and $u(x) = \limsup\limits_{y \to x} \sup\{v(y): v \in S\} < \infty$?

I think that the statement is true. Or, at least, I've not been able to produce a counterexample (under these assumptions). The problem arised while working on a generalization of the dominated convergence theorem (but the origin is not relevant to the statement).

Comment: You can't. ${}{}$

Comment: @user296602 Why not?

Comment: Because it's false. Have you actually tried anything, and where did you encounter this problem? What background do you have? I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't have any of your own thoughts or efforts.

Comment: @user296602 And why is that?

Comment: @user296602 I don't think that it's false. Or, at least, I've not been able to produce a counterexample. The problem arised while working on a generalization of the dominated convergence theorem (but the origin is not relevant to the statement).

Comment: This is one of the most convoluted setups I've ever seen haha. Goodness. This isn't a knock on you, OP, it's just bizarre.

Comment: Say $S = \{ 1_{[k, k+1)} \mid k\in \mathbb Z\}$ or even better $S = \{ 1_x \mid x \in \mathbb R \}$.

Comment: @user251257 I had forgotten to define $\mu$. I edited the question. Unfortunately the counterexample does not work anymore.

Comment: @Riku it still works, as $\mu(\mathbb R) = \infty$. Do you want $\mu$ to be finite?

Comment: @user251257 I don't see how it works.

Comment: @Riku do you see that $\sup S = 1_{\mathbb R}$?

Comment: @user251257 Which is in $L^1$ since $\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-2x} dL < \infty$.

Comment: @Riku you know, $x$ may take negative values...

Comment: @user251257 You're right. I forgot the modulus. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @Riku surely you can adapt my counter example to find a counter example for that $\mu$. Hint: $L = ... \mu$.

Comment: @user251257 Hmm, I think that the assumption $\sup\{v(y): v \in S\} < \infty$ does not make that approach viable.

Comment: @Riku it does. Just try it

Comment: @user251257 I did. Maybe I missed something. Would you mind elaborating in an answer, please?

Comment: Consider $S = \{ e^{2|x|} 1_{x} \mid x\in\mathbb R\}$. Then $\sup S$ is finite-valued function, but obviously unbounded.

Comment: @user251257 I see. Let's assume that the functions in $S$ are uniformly bounded then.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to show is false.

As a counterexample, consider the set $S = \{f_n : n \in \Bbb{N}\}$ with $f_n(x) = 1_{(1,n)}(x)/x$.

I leave it to you to verify $u(x) = 1_{[1,\infty)}(x) /x$, which is not in $L^1$.

With the updated form of the question, take
$f_n (x) = e^{2x} 1_{(1,n)}(x)/x$, so that $u(x) = e^{2x} 1_{[1,\infty)}(x)/x$.

---

---

With the updated updated answer, the answer is true: It is not hard to see that $\mu$ is a finite measure. Furthermore, the family $S$ is now uniformly bounded, say $|v(x)|\leq C$ for all $v \in S$ and $x\in \Bbb{R}$. This easily(!) implies $|u(y)|\leq C$. Since $\mu$ is a finite measure, this implies $u \in L^1$.

Finally: the above is only true if $u$ is measurable. For general (uncountable) $S$, this might fail!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I had forgotten to write down in the question that $S$ is a family of functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that are bounded (but not necessarily uniformly bounded) and in $L^1(\mu)$, where $\mu = e^{-2x}L$, where $L$ is the Lebesgue measure. So this does not work as a counterexample. But thank you anyway.

Comment: @Riku: I updated my answer.

Comment: But we need to have $\sup\{v(y): v \in S\} < \infty$. And I don't think that's the case with $e^{2x} 1_{[1,\infty)}(x)/x$ in your example.

Comment: (Also, I forgot a modulus: it should read $\mu = e^{-2|x|}L$)

Comment: @Riku: Updated again.

Comment: Thank you. Why do we have that $\mu$ is a finite measure? And why for uncountable $S$ the argument might fail?